# Mongoengine AttributeError

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to code authorization for app using Flask-Mongoengine and Flask-Login. And I'm getting this weird error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 188, in __setattr__
    super(BaseDocument, self).__setattr__(name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 132, in __set__
    if instance._initialised:
AttributeError: _initialised
```

My models.py:

```
from app import app, db
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


class User(db.Document):
    email = db.StringField(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_lenght=40, required=True)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_lenght=40, required=True)
    password = db.StringField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.password = password

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

   def get_id(self):
        return self.email
```

I've tried supering the class, but it didn't help.

https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/156

Comment: Do you have any update or fix on this?

Answer (score 6):

Mongoengine doesn't need you to define an __init__.

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.StringField(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_lenght=40, required=True)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_lenght=40, required=True)
    password = db.StringField(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        # clean will be called when you call .save()
        # You can do whatever you'd like to clean data before save
        self.password = str(self.password)
```

Then all you have to do is

```
user = User(email='email@gmail', first_name='hello', last_name='there', password=2342143213)
user.save()
print(user.id)
```

Answer (score 4):

The fix for this issue, is that you need to invoke the constructor of the super class like this

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.StringField(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_lenght=40, required=True)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_lenght=40, required=True)
    password = db.StringField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.password = password

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

   def get_id(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 2):

Super Class hasn't been created, you have to call super, as like below;

```
def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
    ***super().__init__()***
    self.email = email
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.password = password
```

Answer (score 1):

Future readers should be aware than in [knittledan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834248/knittledan) answer, `clean()` is called before **every** `save()` invocation, so if it's used to hash the password field in the model, eg:

```
def clean(self):
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(self.password).decode('utf-8')
```

the password will be override constantly, something not desired. A workaround is to use an additional field, eg: `password_hashed = db.BooleanField(default=False)`

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.password_hashed:
        self.password        = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(self.password).decode('utf-8')
        self.password_hashed = True
```